Motor stalling with esp32
I need help with an issue, I am making a custom flight controller using an esp32 based on this repository: https://github.com/pratikPhadte/ESP32-Flight-controller-.git, I adapted the code to try and use the drone with a ps4 controller at close range, however, when I start increasing the throttle, one of the motors stops running, is it possible it is a software issue? this is the code I am working with:
#include <Wire.h>
#include <ESP32Servo.h> // Change to the standard Servo library for ESP32
#include <PS4Controller.h>

volatile float RatePitch, RateRoll, RateYaw;
volatile float RateCalibrationPitch, RateCalibrationRoll, RateCalibrationYaw;
int RateCalibrationNumber;

Servo mot1;
Servo mot2;
Servo mot3;
Servo mot4;
const int mot1_pin = 23;
const int mot2_pin = 15;
const int mot3_pin = 13;
const int mot4_pin = 32 ;


volatile int ReceiverValue[6]; // Increase the array size to 6 for Channel 1 to Channel 6


// float voltage;

float DesiredRateRoll, DesiredRatePitch, DesiredRateYaw;
float ErrorRateRoll, ErrorRatePitch, ErrorRateYaw;
float InputRoll, InputThrottle, InputPitch, InputYaw;
float PrevErrorRateRoll, PrevErrorRatePitch, PrevErrorRateYaw;
float PrevItermRateRoll, PrevItermRatePitch, PrevItermRateYaw;
float PIDReturn[] = {0, 0, 0};



float PRateRoll = 0.75; //For outdoor flights, keep this gain to 0.75 and for indoor flights keep the gain to be 0.6
float IRateRoll = 0.012;
float DRateRoll = 0.0085;

float PRatePitch = PRateRoll;
float IRatePitch = IRateRoll;
float DRatePitch = DRateRoll;

float PRateYaw = 4.2;
float IRateYaw = 2.8;
float DRateYaw = 0;

uint32_t LoopTimer;
float t=0.006;      //time cycle

//Kalman filters for angle mode
volatile float AccX, AccY, AccZ;
volatile float AngleRoll, AnglePitch;
volatile float KalmanAngleRoll=0, KalmanUncertaintyAngleRoll=2*2;
volatile float KalmanAnglePitch=0, KalmanUncertaintyAnglePitch=2*2;
volatile float Kalman1DOutput[]={0,0};
volatile float DesiredAngleRoll, DesiredAnglePitch;
volatile float ErrorAngleRoll, ErrorAnglePitch;
volatile float PrevErrorAngleRoll, PrevErrorAnglePitch;
volatile float PrevItermAngleRoll, PrevItermAnglePitch;
float PAngleRoll=2; float PAnglePitch=PAngleRoll;
float IAngleRoll=0; float IAnglePitch=IAngleRoll;
float DAngleRoll=0; float DAnglePitch=DAngleRoll;
void kalman_1d(float KalmanState, float KalmanUncertainty, float KalmanInput, float KalmanMeasurement) {
  KalmanState=KalmanState + (t*KalmanInput);
  KalmanUncertainty=KalmanUncertainty + (t*t*4*4); //here 4 is the vairnece of IMU i.e 4 deg/s
  float KalmanGain=KalmanUncertainty * 1/(1*KalmanUncertainty + 3 * 3); //std deviation of error is 3 deg
  KalmanState=KalmanState+KalmanGain * (KalmanMeasurement-KalmanState);
  KalmanUncertainty=(1-KalmanGain) * KalmanUncertainty;
  Kalman1DOutput[0]=KalmanState; 
  Kalman1DOutput[1]=KalmanUncertainty;
}
void read_receiver(){
  ReceiverValue[0]=map(PS4.RStickY(),-127, 127, 1000, 2000);
  ReceiverValue[1]=map(PS4.RStickX(),-127, 127, 1000, 2000);
  ReceiverValue[2]=map(PS4.R2Value(),0, 255, 1000, 2000);
  ReceiverValue[3]=map(PS4.LStickX(),-127, 127, 1000, 2000);
  
  }

volatile float MotorInput1, MotorInput2, MotorInput3, MotorInput4;


void neutralPositionAdjustment()
{
  int min = 1490;
  int max = 1510;
  if (ReceiverValue[0] < max && ReceiverValue[0] > min)
  {
    ReceiverValue[0]= 1500;
  } 
  if (ReceiverValue[1] < max && ReceiverValue[1] > min)
  {
    ReceiverValue[1]= 1500;
  } 
  if (ReceiverValue[3] < max && ReceiverValue[3] > min)
  {
    ReceiverValue[3]= 1500;
  } 
  if(ReceiverValue[0]==ReceiverValue[1] && ReceiverValue[1]==ReceiverValue[3] && ReceiverValue[3]==ReceiverValue[0] )
  {
    ReceiverValue[0]= 1500;
    ReceiverValue[1]= 1500;
    ReceiverValue[3]= 1500;
  }



}
void gyro_signals(void)
{
Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x1A);
  Wire.write(0x05);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x1C);
  Wire.write(0x10);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x3B);
  Wire.endTransmission(); 
  Wire.requestFrom(0x68,6);
  int16_t AccXLSB = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  int16_t AccYLSB = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  int16_t AccZLSB = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x1B); 
  Wire.write(0x8);
  Wire.endTransmission();                                                   
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x43);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(0x68,6);
  int16_t GyroX=Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read();
  int16_t GyroY=Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read();
  int16_t GyroZ=Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read();
  RateRoll=(float)GyroX/65.5;
  RatePitch=(float)GyroY/65.5;
  RateYaw=(float)GyroZ/65.5;
  AccX=(float)AccXLSB/4096;
  AccY=(float)AccYLSB/4096;
  AccZ=(float)AccZLSB/4096;
  AccZ=AccZ+0.08; // calibration offset
  AccX=AccX-0.04;
  AngleRoll=atan(AccY/sqrt(AccX*AccX+AccZ*AccZ))*1/(3.142/180);
  AnglePitch=-atan(AccX/sqrt(AccY*AccY+AccZ*AccZ))*1/(3.142/180);
}

void pid_equation(float Error, float P, float I, float D, float PrevError, float PrevIterm)
{
  float Pterm = P * Error;
  float Iterm = PrevIterm +( I * (Error + PrevError) * (t/2));
  if (Iterm > 400)
  {
    Iterm = 400;
  }
  else if (Iterm < -400)
  {
  Iterm = -400;
  }
  float Dterm = D *( (Error - PrevError)/t);
  float PIDOutput = Pterm + Iterm + Dterm;
  if (PIDOutput > 400)
  {
    PIDOutput = 400;
  }
  else if (PIDOutput < -400)
  {
    PIDOutput = -400;
  }
  PIDReturn[0] = PIDOutput;
  PIDReturn[1] = Error;
  PIDReturn[2] = Iterm;
}

void reset_pid(void)
{
  PrevErrorRateRoll=0; PrevErrorRatePitch=0; PrevErrorRateYaw=0;
  PrevItermRateRoll=0; PrevItermRatePitch=0; PrevItermRateYaw=0;
  PrevErrorAngleRoll=0; PrevErrorAnglePitch=0;    
  PrevItermAngleRoll=0; PrevItermAnglePitch=0;
}




void setup(void) {
PS4.begin();

int led_time=100;
 pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  delay(led_time);
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  delay(led_time);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  delay(led_time);
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  delay(led_time);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  delay(led_time);
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  delay(led_time);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);


  read_receiver();
  
  Wire.setClock(400000);
  Wire.begin();
  delay(250);
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x68);
  Wire.write(0x6B);
  Wire.write(0x00);
  Wire.endTransmission();

 
  mot1.attach(mot1_pin,1000,2000);
  mot2.attach(mot2_pin,1000,2000);
  mot3.attach(mot3_pin,1000,2000);
  mot4.attach(mot4_pin,1000,2000);
//to stop esc from beeping
  mot1.write(0);
  mot2.write(0);
  mot3.write(0);
  mot4.write(0); 
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  delay(2000);


  for (RateCalibrationNumber = 0; RateCalibrationNumber < 4000; RateCalibrationNumber++)
  {
    gyro_signals();
    RateCalibrationRoll += RateRoll;
    RateCalibrationPitch += RatePitch;
    RateCalibrationYaw += RateYaw;
    delay(1);
  }
  RateCalibrationRoll /= 4000;
  RateCalibrationPitch /= 4000;
  RateCalibrationYaw /= 4000;
//Gyro Calibrated Values
  // Serial.print("Gyro Calib: ");
  // Serial.print(RateCalibrationRoll);
  // Serial.print("  ");
  // Serial.print(RateCalibrationPitch);
  // Serial.print("  ");
  // Serial.print(RateCalibrationYaw);
  // Serial.print(" -- ");


  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  delay(1000);



PS4.setLed(0, 255, 0);
  PS4.sendToController();
  

LoopTimer = micros();


} 

void loop(void) {
  gyro_signals();
   RateRoll -= RateCalibrationRoll;
   RatePitch -= RateCalibrationPitch;
   RateYaw -= RateCalibrationYaw;


  kalman_1d(KalmanAngleRoll, KalmanUncertaintyAngleRoll, RateRoll, AngleRoll);
  KalmanAngleRoll=Kalman1DOutput[0]; KalmanUncertaintyAngleRoll=Kalman1DOutput[1];
  kalman_1d(KalmanAnglePitch, KalmanUncertaintyAnglePitch, RatePitch, AnglePitch);
  KalmanAnglePitch=Kalman1DOutput[0]; KalmanUncertaintyAnglePitch=Kalman1DOutput[1];
  
  read_receiver();
  neutralPositionAdjustment();

  DesiredAngleRoll=0.1*(ReceiverValue[0]-1500);
    DesiredAnglePitch=0.1*(ReceiverValue[1]-1500);
  InputThrottle=ReceiverValue[2];
  DesiredRateYaw=0.15*(ReceiverValue[3]-1500);

  ErrorAngleRoll=DesiredAngleRoll-KalmanAngleRoll;
  ErrorAnglePitch=DesiredAnglePitch-KalmanAnglePitch;

  pid_equation(ErrorAngleRoll, PAngleRoll, IAngleRoll, DAngleRoll, PrevErrorAngleRoll, PrevItermAngleRoll);     
  DesiredRateRoll=PIDReturn[0]; 
  PrevErrorAngleRoll=PIDReturn[1];
  PrevItermAngleRoll=PIDReturn[2];

  pid_equation(ErrorAnglePitch, PAnglePitch, IAnglePitch, DAnglePitch, PrevErrorAnglePitch, PrevItermAnglePitch);
  DesiredRatePitch=PIDReturn[0]; 
  PrevErrorAnglePitch=PIDReturn[1];
  PrevItermAnglePitch=PIDReturn[2];

  ErrorRateRoll=DesiredRateRoll-RateRoll;
  ErrorRatePitch=DesiredRatePitch-RatePitch;
  ErrorRateYaw=DesiredRateYaw-RateYaw;

  pid_equation(ErrorRateRoll, PRateRoll, IRateRoll, DRateRoll, PrevErrorRateRoll, PrevItermRateRoll);
       InputRoll=PIDReturn[0];
       PrevErrorRateRoll=PIDReturn[1]; 
       PrevItermRateRoll=PIDReturn[2];

  pid_equation(ErrorRatePitch, PRatePitch,IRatePitch, DRatePitch, PrevErrorRatePitch, PrevItermRatePitch);
       InputPitch=PIDReturn[0]; 
       PrevErrorRatePitch=PIDReturn[1]; 
       PrevItermRatePitch=PIDReturn[2];

  pid_equation(ErrorRateYaw, PRateYaw,IRateYaw, DRateYaw, PrevErrorRateYaw, PrevItermRateYaw);
       InputYaw=PIDReturn[0]; 
       PrevErrorRateYaw=PIDReturn[1]; 
       PrevItermRateYaw=PIDReturn[2];

  if (InputThrottle > 1800)
  {
    InputThrottle = 1800;
  }

  
  MotorInput1 =  (InputThrottle - InputRoll - InputPitch - InputYaw); // front right - counter clockwise
  MotorInput2 =  (InputThrottle - InputRoll + InputPitch + InputYaw); // rear right - clockwise
  MotorInput3 =  (InputThrottle + InputRoll + InputPitch - InputYaw); // rear left  - counter clockwise
  MotorInput4 =  (InputThrottle + InputRoll - InputPitch + InputYaw); //front left - clockwise


  if (MotorInput1 > 2000)
  {
    MotorInput1 = 1999;
  }

  if (MotorInput2 > 2000)
  {
    MotorInput2 = 1999;
  }

  if (MotorInput3 > 2000)
  {
    MotorInput3 = 1999;
  }

  if (MotorInput4 > 2000)
  {
    MotorInput4 = 1999;
  }


  int ThrottleIdle = 1150;
  if (MotorInput1 < ThrottleIdle)
  {
    MotorInput1 = ThrottleIdle;
  }
  if (MotorInput2 < ThrottleIdle)
  {
    MotorInput2 = ThrottleIdle;
  }
  if (MotorInput3 < ThrottleIdle)
  {
    MotorInput3 = ThrottleIdle;
  }
  if (MotorInput4 < ThrottleIdle)
  {
    MotorInput4 = ThrottleIdle;
  }

  int ThrottleCutOff = 1000;
  if (ReceiverValue[2] < 1050)
  {
    MotorInput1 = ThrottleCutOff;
    MotorInput2 = ThrottleCutOff;
    MotorInput3 = ThrottleCutOff;
    MotorInput4 = ThrottleCutOff;
    reset_pid();
  }

  mot1.write(map(MotorInput1, 1000, 2000, 0, 180));
  mot2.write(map(MotorInput2, 1000, 2000, 0, 180));
  mot3.write(map(MotorInput3, 1000, 2000, 0, 180));
  mot4.write(map(MotorInput4, 1000, 2000, 0, 180));



 
  while (micros() - LoopTimer < (t*1000000)); 
  {
     LoopTimer = micros();

  }

}

I tried to change the calibration values and I even replaced the motors, nothing seems to work

Do you use any specific motor drivers?
